# Sumar los números mayores a X en un arreglo

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de sumar los números mayores a x y restar los números menores a x. Hice una función que saca un número aleatorio del arreglo, y ese número será el X. Despúes lo compare con el arreglo, pero no me funciona:(. Aquí les dejo el código. Gracias!

```
 public void llenaArreglo(){
    int n = getRandom(array);int mayores=0,menores=0;
    for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*30+1);
    }
}

public int getRandom(int[] array) { //Obtiene un número aleatorio del arreglo
int random = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
return array[random];
}

public String sumayResta(int[] array){//Obtiene los numeros mayores y menores a X
    int n = getRandom(array);int suma=0,resta=0;String cadena="";
    for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if (array[i]>n)
            suma+=array[i];
        else
            resta-=array[i];
   }
    cadena = "Suma: "+suma+"\nResta: "+resta;
    return cadena; 
}
```

Comment: No me funciona.. que quiere decir? tira un error? da un resultado que no deberia dar? no termina? no me funciona es muy amplio y no podemos adivinar que pasa...

Comment: Me quería referir a que cuando ejecuto la función sumayResta, no suma los numeros mayores a "X", y pasa lo mismo con la resta.

Comment: Y eso es lo que tiene que decir tu pregunta.. no somos adivinos...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revisando los aportes que haces respecto a tu código, veo algunas cosas que no se están interpretando como se debe y otras no se realiza como son.

1. Empecemos revisando la funcion `getRandom`, observo que la usas para 2 cosas. Primero intentas hacer que se llene de manera random el arreglo que tienes, con valores entre 1 y 30. Segundo, intentas tomar un valor aleatorio del arreglo y ese seria el valor x.

   Como planteas dicha función no va a cumplir lo que deseas. Para ello he realizado un ajuste en la función donde quedaría de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   /**
    * El parametro es nulo cuando se desea llenar el arreglo con valores,
    * es diferente de nulo cuando se desea retornar una posicion random del arreglo.
    * @param array
    * @return
    */
   public int getRandom(int[] array) { //Obtiene un número aleatorio del arreglo

       if (array == null) {
           return new Random().nextInt(30) + 1; // De esta manera hacemos que retorne el valor rando entre el 1 y el 30
       } else {
           return new Random().nextInt(array.length); // De esta manera hacemos que se retorne la posicion del arreglo
       }
   }
   ```
2. Pasemos a revisar el método `llenaArreglo`. Este método, inicializa variables que no se usan, se ejecuta la funcion `getRandom` donde lo que retorna tampoco se usa. Se realiza un for recorriendo el arreglo, para así realizar la asignación de los valores al arreglo mediante la funcion `random` de la clase `Math`, Se recomienda hacer uso de la función `nextInt` de la clase `Random` de java.util. Para esto podemos hacer uso de la misma función getRandom que se propuso en el punto anterior, quedando el método `llenaArreglo` de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   /**
    * Se recorre el arreglo y se le asignan valores random
    */
   public void llenaArreglo(){
       for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
           array[i] = getRandom(null);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Por último la funcion `sumayResta` que propones, tiene lo siguiente.

   - Se obtiene el valor n, que usas como el valor x, pero realmente la funcion que hiciste del getRandom, lo que retorna es la posición, mas no el valor que se encuentra en la posición random.
   - Se observa que la función suma cuando el valor de la variable n, es menor a cada item del arreglo y resta cuando el valor del item es mayor o igual al valor de n. y según lo que especificaste en un comienzo, el valor para restar debe ser menor solamente.

   Partiendo de lo mencionado se muestra a continuación la solución propuesta de como debería estar la función `sumayResta`

   ```
   /**
    * Retorna los numeros mayores y menores a X
    * @param array
    * @return
    */
   public String sumayResta(int[] array) {

       int x = array[getRandom(array)]; // Obtenemos el valor x, accediendo a la posicion random que se retorna en la funcion getRandom
       int suma = 0;
       int resta = 0;
       String cadena = "";

       for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
           if (array[i] > x) // Si es mayor que x, se suman los valores
               suma += array[i];
           else if (array[i] < x) // Si es menor que x, se restan los valores
               resta -= array[i];
       }

       cadena = "X: " + x + "\nSuma: "+suma+"\nResta: "+resta;

       return cadena; 
   }
   ```

En mi caso he tenido que declarar las funciones y métodos estáticos para la prueba, pero te comparto el código funcional que hice con el main para que puedas observarlo completo.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class SumasRestas {

    private static int[] array = new int[5];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            llenaArreglo();
            System.out.println("Arreglo: " + Arrays.toString(array));
            System.out.println(sumayResta(array));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    /**
     * Se recorre el arreglo y se le asignan valores random
     */
    public static void llenaArreglo(){
        for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            array[i] = getRandom(null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * El parametro es nulo cuando se desea llenar el arreglo con valores,
     * es diferente de nulo cuando se desea retornar una posicion random del arreglo.
     * @param array
     * @return
     */
    public static int getRandom(int[] array) { //Obtiene un número aleatorio del arreglo

        if (array == null) {
            return new Random().nextInt(30) + 1; // De esta manera hacemos que retorne el valor rando entre el 1 y el 30
        } else {
            return new Random().nextInt(array.length); // De esta manera hacemos que se retorne la posicion del arreglo
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retorna los numeros mayores y menores a X
     * @param array
     * @return
     */
    public static String sumayResta(int[] array) {

        int x = array[getRandom(array)]; // Obtenemos el valor x, accediendo a la posicion random que se retorna en la funcion getRandom
        int suma = 0;
        int resta = 0;
        String cadena = "";

        for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            if (array[i] > x) // Si es mayor que x, se suman los valores
                suma += array[i];
            else if (array[i] < x) // Si es menor que x, se restan los valores
                resta -= array[i];
        }
        cadena = "X: " + x + "\nSuma: "+suma+"\nResta: "+resta;
        return cadena; 
    }
}
```

Espero haber sido claro, saludos.

Comment: Excelente! Me aclaraste varias dudas que tenia :D. Tengo solo una duda, porque en la función getRandom() igualaste el array a null?

Comment: bueno, lo que hice es 2 cosas, usar la funcion random para que retorne valores entre el 1 y el 30 que es cuando el parámtro lo mandamos nulo desde el método llenarArreglo. Ya que allí no tenemos info aun en el arreglo. Y la segunda parte donde la usamos, es para retornar del arreglo una posición aleatoria. Que en ese segundo llamado lo que hacemos es mandarle como parámetro el arreglo real.

Answer (score 2):

He revisado tu código y funciona, solamente revisé los métodos `getRandom()` y `sumayResta()`, solamente encontré un posible error en las condiciones.

Tú lo tienes así, pero esto restará también el número X, cuando en tu problema dices que solos los menores a X.

```
 if (array[i]>n)
   suma+=array[i];
 else
  resta-=array[i];
```

Por lo tanto si el número X no se suma ni se resta el código queda de la siguiente manera.

```
if (array[i] > n)
  suma += array[i];
else if (array[i] < n)
  resta -= array[i];
```

Probé con este arreglo `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]`

Donde `X = 6`

```
Suma = 7, 8, 9, 10 = 27

Resta = 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 = - 15
```

Deberías agregar más detalles para saber en qué orden llamas los métodos que tienes o con que valores has realizado tus pruebas, los resultados obtenidos y los resultados esperados, probablemente mandar a llamar el método `sumayResta()` sin que el array tenga valores.